# are ZODB PersistentLists lazily loaded?

Tags: python, zodb

If I load an object which has several PersistentList attributes - are the lists automatically loaded in their entirety? Or does ZODB wait until I access an element of the list to load it? If the latter, does it load the entire list whenever an element is accessed, or only part of the list?

Comment: PersistentList content items are loaded when accessed by index. Normal Python lists are pickled as a whole in ZODB.

Comment: Mikko: this would answer the question - do you care adding that as an answer isntead of a comment?

Comment: Well, it's a little more complex than that; PersistentList is itself not lazy-loading, but the ZODB *is*, provided the records inherit from Persistent. See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Provided your elements *inside* the list are themselves inheriting from `persistent.Persistent`, they will be loaded on demand.

Primitive types and classes that do not inherit from `Persistent`, however, are loaded into memory together with the PersistentList instance.

PersistentList is basically a subclass of [`UserList`](http://docs.python.org/library/userdict.html#module-UserList) (and `Persistent`) that sets `self._p_changed` when altered, so that changes to the list are translated into a ZODB commit for it's record.

Comment: I think it is important to emphasize that lazy loading is a behaviour of references to Persistent objects, and not of PersistentList. You also get lazy loading with a std python list with references to Persistent objects, and with a object graph of  Persistent objects.